# How can I filter a results table with multiple forms/multiple options in one form in django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to have one page with multiple filter options (e.g. Name, Abbreviation, Country, ...) where you can type Sweden in the form and only get the results of Institutions in Sweden OR type the name/abbreviation/... when you press the 'search' button. The search button then redirects you to the filtered result table.

forms.py

```
class InstitutionsForm(forms.Form):
     name = forms.CharField(label='Name', required=False)
     abbreviation = forms.CharField(label='Abbreviation', required=False)
```

views.py

```
def institution_search_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InstitutionsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return institution_results_name(request, form)  
    else:
        context = {
            "form": InstitutionsForm
        }
        return render(request,"stakeholders/institution_form.html", context)

def institution_results_name(request, form):
    all_insts = Institution.objects.filter(name=form.cleaned_data["name"])
    context = {
    "result_data":=SafeString(serializers.serialize("json", all_insts)),
    }
    return render(request, "landing/result_table.html", context)
```

institution_form.html

```
<form method="post">
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

So far I do get all the CharFields I defined in forms.py on one page.

My problem is that I cannot search for the countries, abbreviation, etc. only 'Name' does work.

I tried to write different forms and even put them on different urls, but all just filtered after the typed in name. With a country I just get an empty results table.

I also tried to write different views for each form and changed 'name' with 'country' everywhere, but still cannot get the right results.

```
def institution_results_country(request, form):
    all_insts = Institution.objects.filter(name=form.cleaned_data["country"])
    context = {
    "result_data":=SafeString(serializers.serialize("json", all_insts)),
    }
    return render(request, "landing/result_table.html", context)
```

(same with the institution_search_form. -> `institution_search_form_country().... return institution_country()`)

Hope someone can help me!
All ideas are welcome :)

Comment: Why are you separating the views? One view should do everything.

Comment: You can create one form with name, abbreviation and country. Use one view to filter the results based on the input provided by the user.

Comment: If I put it in one view the result doesn't change. 
It still filters just by the name.

Comment: If all options of the form are added to the view (
like that: `"result_data": SafeString(serializers.serialize("json", all_insts_abbreviation)),
                "result_data": SafeString(serializers.serialize("json", all_insts_name)),
                "result_data": SafeString(serializers.serialize("json", all_insts_country)),`

The result is allways the last one in the row. In this example 'country'.

Comment: You want the user to provide name, abbreviation and country. Then your view will filter institutions based on that, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like this. You have to create a form with three fields which are name, abbreviation and country. Make all these fields to `required=False` . Following is code for the form.

```
# Your form 
class SearchInstitutionsForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    abbreviation = forms.CharField(required=False)
    country = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

Now in the searching view you have to filter based on the fields that have been filled out by the user. Your view would be like this.

```
    # Your search view
    def search_institutions(request):
        form = SearchInstitutionsForm()
        qs = Institution.objects.all()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = SearchInstitutionsForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                if cd['name']:
                    qs = Institution.objects.filter(name__contains=cd['name'])
                if cd['abbreviation']:
                    qs = Institution.objects.filter(
                        abbreviation__contains=cd['abbreviation'])
                if cd['country']:
                    qs = Institution.objects.filter(
                        country__contains=cd['country']
                    )
        
        context {
            'result_data':=SafeString(serialize.serialize("json", qs)),
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request, "landing/result_table.html", context)
```

Comment: This code just gives the complete result table without the form/input option. Do I need to combine it differently?
And why is the `else:` not longer needed?

Comment: Never mind :D 
With my 'else: ... '  added it works totally fine! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In your case (only name works) is due to you are specifying name in **filter** method. If you need to filter based on more fields then indicate them also. For more info see [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter).

So if you want to filter based on 2 columns name and country then your function will look like something below:

```
def institution_results_country(request, form):
    all_insts = Institution.objects.filter(name=form.cleaned_data["name"], country=form.cleaned_data["country"])
    context = {
    "result_data":=SafeString(serializers.serialize("json", all_insts)),
    }
    return render(request, "landing/result_table.html", context)
```